# Visual Studio 2008 crashes when trying to load solution file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crash, add-in

When I try to load a solution in Visual Studio 2008, it immediately closes. I get the following error in the event log:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 -
>   Fatal Execution Engine Error
>   (6E875E00) (80131506)

I've searched the web high and low and can't find a resolution to this problem. I've found similar issues, but none of them match the (6E875E00) part. Here's my setup:

Vista 64
Visual Studio 2008 SP1
.Net Framework 3.5 SP1
ReSharper 4.1
Gallio 3.05
TestDriven.Net 2.18

I have a feeling it is one of the add-ins, but I don't know which one.

Anyone experience this? This is very frustrating!

EDIT: The answer to this problem for future reference was to uninstall Gallio. This was the only add-in that caused the crash. Thanks to all for the help!

Comment: Is it related to a specific solution or to any solution file?

Comment: several solution files. it seems more likely to happen to solutions that have a web project as part of it, but I haven't verified yet that to be sure.

Comment: I experienced this after installing the PowerCommands addon - oh well, don't need that much power, anyway!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating a new solution and importing your existing projects.

Alternitivly, uninstall ReShaper, Gallio and TestDriven and see if the solution loads. Then install one addin at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: The alternative solution worked. It ends up that Gallio was the culprit. I uninstalled all of the add-ins and one at a time installed one, opened an affected solution, and then uninstalled the add-in. All of the add-ins worked fine, except for Gallio. Installing all of them without Gallio also works

Comment: I had the same symptoms as you, but the buggered addon was PowerTools.

Comment: PowerTools always sound nice, but every time I've installed I've gotten buggered.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that PowerTools can cause the same thing, though I think the error code is (7A035E00), not (6E875E00) that I was getting. I have no idea what the codes mean, but googling my code resulted in no hits, whereas the 7A0 at least pointed to a known issue with PowerTools.

Comment: It was gallio for me: 3.0.6.787

Comment: thanks a lot!! it save me day! It was Gallio to me as well. Gallio team need to spend some time :=)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, not unlikely.  Edit the short-cut to Visual Studio and give it the /SafeMode option.  That ensures Add-Ons don't get loaded.  If that doesn't help, start disabling shrink-wrapped malware like virus scanners.

Answer (score 5):

If it's only affecting a single solution, try deleting the .suo file (it'll be in the same folder as the solution file); If it affects all solutions, then the safemode option that nobugz mentions is probably worth trying...

Answer (score 3):

Try resetting windows layout (Menu -> Window -> Reset Window Layout) before loading the solution.

This helps me on VS crashes.

Comment: This worked for me.  Loading was failing whenever I launched VS from a .sln file, but working fine for File->Open(.sln File)

Comment: Oddly this worked for me too - none of the other suggestions in this and other places worked!

Answer (score 2):

We had similar problems with Visual Studio crashing on startup, and the culprit was a specific add-on, namely the Visual Studio PowerCommands.

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/PowerCommands

Beware this add-in! Disabling it and running

> devenv /ResetSkipPackages

Helped. The [full list of VS command line params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(VS.80).aspx) is also instructive.

Comment: Just to have two opinions on the "beware" note, I've personally not had any troubles with this add-on.

Comment: the comments on the first answer also indicate problems with this add-on, which is why we started looking at it. FYI.

Comment: for future reference, i believe it's devenv /ResetSkipPkgs       
not /ResetSkipPakages

Answer (score 0):

Try this Fix:

http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/03/03/hotfix-available-for-asp-net-mvc-crashes-with-azure-power-commands-resharper.aspx

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

Devenv.exe /ResetSettings