# Visual Studio crashes when I try to open a solution under TFS source control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I am having some troubles opening solutions in VS2008 which are under source control by TFS.

- opening solutions outside of source control works fine
- opening single projects is OK
- others can open these solutions
- VS crashes without any notice, the logfile ends without any closing tags etc.

Anyone ran across this problem before me?

I've tried all the suggestions in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438923/visual-studio-2008-crashes-when-trying-to-load-solution-file).

EDIT:

I've tried to run VS in SafeMode /ResetSkipPkgs etc. nothing helped and no error message was shown (Log and VS).

Edit2:

After trying all this I nuked my Visual Studio installation now it's working.

Comment: You tried running it in Safe-Mode (will show the error)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be related at all, however, I had a similar problem once opening SourceSafe projects and the actual problem was related to the length of the directory structure.

By default, sourcesafe was getting my projects to my "My Documents / My Visual Studio" folder. This, coupled with the directory structure of the solution/project went beyond the directory length visual studio could manage and crashed. I seem to remember the crash not being particularly helpful / informative.

The solution was to ensure that all the SourceSafe working directories were setup in advance to a smaller D:\Projects type directory.

Comment: I've configured a new workspace and move one of my Team Projects to a location D:\TFS\ProjectA\ProjectA.sln which resulted in the same crash.